# React Native ListView - TypeError: Cannot read property 'cloneWithRows' of undefined (…)

Tags: javascript, android, listview, react-native

Trying to create a list view from this api but I keep getting this error

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'cloneWithRows' of undefined (…)**

Probably an easy fix but i am confused!

Heres my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ListView
} from 'react-native';

var heros = [];

class Heros extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    var dataSource = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 != r2})
    this.state = {
      peopleDataSource: dataSource.cloneWithRows(heros)
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getHeros(function(json){
    heros = json;
    this.setState = ({
      datasource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(heros),
      isLoading:false
    })
  }.bind(this));

  }

  getHeros(callback) {
    var url = "https://api.lootbox.eu/xbl/us/Food%20Market/competitive-play/heroes";
    fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => callback(json))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <ListView
          style={{marginTop: 100}}
          dataSource={this.state.peopleDataSource}
          renderRow={(person) => { return this._renderPersonRow(heros)
          enableEmptySections={true} }} />
      </View>
    )
  }

  _renderPersonRow(person) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.personRow}>
        <Text style={styles.PersonName}> {person.name} </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

module.exports = Heros;

Answer (score 2):

Your data store variable is named `peopleDataSource` (declared in the constructor) yet you are trying to access it with `this.state.dataSource`. It should be `this.state.peopleDataSource`. Should be:

```
this.setState = ({
  peopleDataSource: this.state.peopleDataSource.cloneWithRows(heros),
  isLoading:false
})
```